# Only printing error messages once per loop

Tags: python, for-loop, error-handling

I have some Python that looks like this:

```
for row in reader:
    if # something
       # do things
    else:
        try:
            # do more things
        except IndexError:
            logger.info('message')
```

What ends up happening is I get a huge wall of output that says `INFO:...message` for each iteration of the loop. There's no need for it to appear what could be over 1,000 times. I could use a 'flag' of sorts after I leave the loop, kind of like this:

```
for row in reader
    # if/else/try
        except IndexError:
            foo = True
if foo:
    logger.info('message')
```

But I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to do this. The important bits are that I *do* want to show the error, but only once. And I can't break out of the loop on the error, because I need to continue processing the rest of the `row`s in `reader`. The `IndexError` appears when I try to create a variable from a list that might not exist. I have to do it this way because if the variable does not exist I have to skip over it instead of providing even a blank value.

Thus my weird little predicament. Is there a better way of doing this? Preferably the most 'Pythonic', as speed and what not isn't such a big issue in this case.

Comment: Would a hasattr check for the variable work in this case as perhaps an alternative?

Comment: @tjd.rodgers the variable part is more of a simplification on my part for the sake of making the question easier to digest. What I'm really doing is something like this: http://i.imgur.com/IpyRX9V.png I could use an `if` statement to set the value in the `dict`, but since I could have half of all the `row`s be errors, I'd rather use a `try/except` as there's less overhead. Plus, Python is EAFP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep a counter, sometimes the simplest ways are the best. you could even add a nifty notice at the end.

```
bad = 0
for row in reader:
    if # something
       # do things
    else:
        try:
            # do more things
        except IndexError:
            bad += 1
            if bad == 1:
                logger.info('message')
if bad:
    logger.info('%d bad things happened' % bad)
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess this is the route I'll have to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the warnings module here. With the warning filter https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings, you can display the warning only once.

```
import warnings

def fxn():
    warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("once")
    fxn()
```